# How to setup the paging file (virtual memory) correctly on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server, virtual-memory

I am trying to create 10GB virtual memory on my Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.

I have a 40GB SSD disk.

I've done it already, but at last I see that I have 10GB only available from my 40GB disk... when I remove the virtual memory I get 29GB free of 40GB.

I put 10240 in both the `Initial size (MB) and Maximum size (MB)` fields.

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some articles are explaining what are the function of each of the "Initial size" and the "Maximum size" boxes.

Like this article: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002245

On step 7 (see the bold text below):

> Select Custom size and set Initial size (MB) and Maximum size (MB).
>   **For the initial size, Microsoft recommends using the recommended value**
>   **in the Total paging file size for all drives box.**

And for the "Maximum size" you should put 10240 (10GB as you wanted).

Now, you should see that you have like 26GB free of your 40GB disk :-)